# select top row using two different dates

Tags: sql

A table has the PriceValidFrom ,  PriceValidTo,   BookingWindowFrom and BookingWindowTo   date fields  and a Price currency field. The client inserts or updates rows randomly.  Some rows may have PriceValid period  shorter than others, but could be inside the same month (and with different price) , for example. Other rows may have identical  PriceValid periods but may differ only in the BookingWindow period. The table is never cleaned and everything is acceptable. 
I need a query that, given a date, will return the price from the row with the highest PriceValidFrom date. In the example below, considering the table and the query statement:

```
PriceValidFrom PriceValidTo Price
05/01/2013     05/30/2013   $100.00
05/15/2013     05/20/2013   $50.00
```

pseudo sql

```
select top 1 price
where :Date between PriceValidFrom and PriceValidTo   
order by PriceValidFrom DESC, Price
```

If the date is 05/16/2013 the query returns $50.00 as expected.

Now, the user needs to add a Booking Window period that must also take the highest BookingWindowFrom:

```
PriceValidFrom PriceValidTo Price     BookingWindowFrom  BookingWindowTo
05/01/2013     05/30/2013   $100.00   4/1/2013           5/30/2013 
05/15/2013     05/20/2013   $50.00    4/1/2013           5/30/2013
05/15/2013     05/20/2013   $75.00    5/1/2013           5/30/2013
```

Now, if the date is 05/16/2013 and the booking date is 5/1/2013 the query needs to return $75.00

How to accomplish the expected result? Please note this is a simplified example but there will be hundreds of rows in the real table.

```
select top 1 price 
where :Date between PriceValidFrom and PriceValidTo    
    and  :BookingDate  between BookingWindowFrom  and  BookingWindowTo
```

Comment: what does effective date ovverides ? validTo?

Comment: Some description or example data showing what to do when an EffectiveDate exists and does not exist would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated  my post. Please take another look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is not the solution, you have to change your `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
SELECT top 1 price     
WHERE EffectiveDate = :pDate
   OR (EffectiveDate IS NULL AND :pDate BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo)

ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC, ValidFrom DESC, Price
```

I am assuming some things about your schema here, but I think this should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess based upon how I *think* you want EffectiveDate used:

```
select top 1 price
where :pDate between coalesce(EffectiveDate, ValidFrom) and ValidTo
order by coalesce(EffectiveDate, ValidFrom) DESC, Price
```

Or do you want to simply toss out all ValidXXX dates if there is an EffectiveDate available?

I would generally suggest using min/max or ranking functions to get the price as opposed to cleverly manipulating the non-ANSI `top` with the order clause, but that's just an opinion.

I must admit that this `EffectiveDate` seems a little hackish at first glance to enable not cleaning up ValidFrom/To dates properly, as in, "We don't want to take the time to correct our data, just make the thing this price right now!"  As such, what is stopping the EffectiveDates from getting too numerous and making it seem like you need to then add a `ReallyEffectiveDate` column?  The words "Valid" and "Effective" seem like synonyms here and could be very confusing to understand and program against.  Okay, assumption-filled rant over.

Comment: Your assumptions are 100% correct. I have updated my post, please take another look at it. Thanks.